# How to calculate numerically 10 integrals in Python

Tags: python, precision, numeric, integral

I need to calculate deterministically the following sum in python using numeric methods.

I have the following function:
[image]

Is there any analogue of `scipy.integrate.tplquad` that can calculate so many integrals?

Comment: Take a look at [nquad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html)

Comment: your integral have an exact solution, you can reagrupate the terms to have `...int_x2 ( int_x1( 
 x_1 e^(-x_1) *x_2 e^(-x_2) ....)` and when no integration limits have another variable you can solve this as the product of integral. And last any of those integral are exactly the same so you can solve only one (lets say `I_1`) and then do I_1^10. Your result will be 1.6595e-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sympy

```
import sympy as sym

x = sym.symbols('x1:11')
expr = sym.prod(x) * sym.exp(-sum(x))
integral = sym.integrate(expr, *((xi, 0, 1) for xi in x))
```

`print(integral)` will show you the explicit expression, though `integral.factor()` will show you a neater form.

```
(-2 + E)**10*exp(-10)    # E is the mathematical constant
```

You can also evaluate that whatever precision you want.

```
>>> integral.evalf()  # this can take an argument `n` for precision digits
1.65960210179703e-6
```